# How do I input each value of a string into each separate element of an integer array C#? Windows Form Application

Tags: c#, arrays, input

I'm new to all this programming fiasco and I was wondering if there was any way to achieve the goal of what my title suggests?

I have an integer array called "LoyaltyNumber"
- int[] LoyaltyNumber = new int [8]

This array is used to validate a discount code.

I have a string called "NumberBoxInput" which consists of the numbers input by the user through a textbox.
- NumberBoxInput = NumberBox.Text

I was wondering if there was a way to put the whole number into the textbox and then put each of those numbers from the textbox into each separate element of the LoyaltyNumber array (Eg. LoyaltyNumber[0] = the first number input into the textbox)

Eg. If the User input into the Textbox was the number: 46764833
How could I make it that LoyaltyNumber[0] = 4, LoyaltyNumber[1] = 6, LoyaltyNumber[2] = 7 and so on?

Comment: Some sample inputs would be nice.  If the textbox number is `"12345678"` do you want the array to be `int[] {1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8}`?

Comment: With numbers you mean digits or actual numbers? If the latter, what is the split criteria?

Comment: Can you share sample imput ?

Comment: string has a method .ToCharArray() that gives you an array of all the chars in a string.  Presumable you'd iterate over this array check if the char is an int and then add it to your LoyaltyNumber array.

Answer (score 0):

As you have mentioned in question regarding user input

***If the User input into the Textbox was the number: 46764833***

Then try following

```
        String inputSample = "46764833";
        var chars = inputSample.ToCharArray().Select(c => c.ToString()).ToArray();
        int[] intLoyaltyNumber2 = Array.ConvertAll(chars, int.Parse);
        for (int ctr = 0; ctr < chars.Length; ctr++)
            Console.WriteLine("{0}: {1}", ctr, chars[ctr]);
```

Answer (score 0):

I would use the `string.Split()` method to put the elements of the string into an  object, then use a `for` loop to assign each element to the array.

Example:

```
//intialize recipient array
int[] numArray = new int[5];

//test string  
string nums = "1,2,3,4,5";

//assign each number to its respective element in the 'numList' array, using the ',' 
//as a separator
string[] numList = nums.Split(','); 

//assign each 'numList' element to the recipient array using a 'for' loop
for (int i = 0; i < numArray.Length; i++)
{             
    //Convert.ToInt32 converts the strings to integers so they can
    //be loaded into the recipient array       
     numArray[i]=Convert.ToInt32(numList[i]);
}
```

Keep in mind that you would need to have some sort of delimiter separating your numbers in the text box (this can be a comma or a space or anything).

You would also need to be sure that your array is big enough to hold all of the numbers that the user wants to give you.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `char[] string.ToCharArray()` function, then convert to int like so:

```
string input = "123456789";
char[] numbersArray = input.ToCharArray();
Console.WriteLine(numbersArray);
//convert to ints ...
```

Or use `Char.IsDigit(char)` for validation like so:

```
string input = "123456789";
int[] numbersArray = new int[numbers.Length];
for (int i = 0; i < numbers.Length; i++)
{                                
     if (Char.IsDigit(numbers[i]))                    
        numbersArray[i] = Int32.Parse(numbers[i].ToString());

     Console.Write(numbersArray[i]);              
}
```

Comment: Sorry missed the int conversion part. Edited the answer.

Answer (score 0):

Try this, it's a one liner:

```
String inputSample = "46764833";


int[] sampleArray = Array.ConvertAll<char, int>(inputSample.ToCharArray().Where(c => Char.IsDigit(c)).ToArray(), System.Convert.ToInt32);
```